# ESP8266 - Request received callback never called

Tags: web, tcp, server, esp8266

Can someone help me figure out why ESP8266 would not call the request received callback in the following code.

```c
wifi_set_opmode(STATIONAP_MODE); 
os_printf("\nTotal Heap at beginning %d\n", system_get_free_heap_size());
struct ip_info info;
struct softap_config cfg;
wifi_softap_get_config(&cfg);
strcpy((char *)cfg.ssid, "ESP8266_VisualGDB");
cfg.ssid_len = strlen((char*)cfg.ssid);
wifi_softap_set_config_current(&cfg);

wifi_softap_dhcps_stop();
IP4_ADDR(&info.ip, 192, 168, 123, 1);
IP4_ADDR(&info.gw, 192, 168, 123, 1);
IP4_ADDR(&info.netmask, 255, 255, 255, 0);
wifi_set_ip_info(SOFTAP_IF, &info);
dhcps_lease_test();
wifi_softap_dhcps_start();

static struct espconn httpdConn;
static esp_tcp httpdTcp;
httpdConn.type = ESPCONN_TCP;
httpdConn.state = ESPCONN_NONE;
httpdTcp.local_port = 80;
httpdConn.proto.tcp = &httpdTcp;


espconn_regist_connectcb(&httpdConn, httpdConnectCb);
espconn_regist_recvcb(&httpdConn, receive_callback);
espconn_accept(&httpdConn);
```

Comment: I noticed your gw is the same as your ip, was that intentional?  Put some serial logging in there to find out what's going on.

Comment: While setting AP mode, it is applicable to having same addr on ip and gw.